# What spells can a Psion learn?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

In the Psionic Handbook, Dungeon and Dragon edition 3.5, on page 7, Table 1.1 shows how many spells you learn for each level.

Example at level 1: you get 2+d spell of level 0 spell. so 2 spell + 1 discipline spell,

What spells which are not from the discipline of the Psion he can take (in the previous exemple the "2")? I search online and in the books and found nothing on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *Psionic Handbook* is from 3.0, not 3.5, and is replaced by *Expanded Psionics Handbook*, which is also (mostly) available for free online as part of the [System Reference Document](https://www.d20srd.org/). PsH is also one of the worst designs in 3.x,<sup>1</sup> while XPH is one of the best.

The [psion](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/classes/psion.htm) learns psionic powers, not spells, and the number of them (in 3.5 anyway) is given in that table labeled The Psion. Discipline powers are explained in the section labeled Discipline, but the psion is never required to learn discipline powers specifically. So at level 1, when the psion knows 3 powers, he may learn all 3 from his special discipline list, or none, or any other proportion in between.

A psion **can**, technically, learn spells by being an erudite psion, as described in *Complete Psionic*, and then using the Convert Spell to Power option for erudites that is presented in [this *Mind’s Eye* article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211001135259/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/psm/20070629a). Note that spell-to-power erudites are often considered one of the most broken classes in the game.

1. <sub>It might be more accurate to say that *Psionic Handbook*’s rules fit into 3.x the worst. Many of the ideas in *Psionic Handbook* would be fine if it were stand-alone, but attempting to shoehorn them into 3.x went very poorly.</sub>

Comment: Note: *Psionic Handbook* is, and I was somewhat surprised to discover this myself, **not** one of the books I own, and my collection is pretty close to complete, having inherited several stashes of books from former DMs. I am making an assumption that *Psionic Handbook* is the source of the “2+d” in the question.

Comment: Psionic Handbook was pretty broken @KRyan. Kineticist Psions primary casting modifier was CON. It was *brutal*.

Comment: @Sandwich I am aware of the severe problems with the book, which is why I never bothered to actually get it, I suppose.

Comment: You can normally pick up a copy at Second & Charles for about four dollars if you want a good laugh.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about Psionic Powers, and not Spells(which the Psion cannot cast):

In the Expanded Psionics book (which is the official 3.5 Psionics book), in the Psion class description you can see this text under the "Discipline" section:

> **Discipline**: Every psion must decide at 1st level which psionic discipline he will specialize in. Choosing a discipline provides a psion with access to the class skills associated with that discipline (see above), as well as the powers restricted to that discipline. However, choosing a discipline also means that **the psion cannot learn powers that are restricted to other disciplines**. He can't even use such powers by employing psionic items. (See Psionic Disciplines, below, for a brief description of each discipline. Chapter 5 of this book contains a list of powers available to all psions and lists of powers restricted to certain disciplines.)

Reading that I understand that you simply cannot learn any power that is restricted to another discipline.

In the next section, "Powers known" there is also this text:

> Choose the powers known from the psion power list, or from the list of powers of your chosen discipline. You cannot choose powers from disciplines other than your chosen discipline. (Exception: The feats Expanded Knowledge, p. 46, and Epic Expanded Knowledge, p. 34, allow a psion to learn powers from the lists of other disciplines or even other classes.) A psion can manifest any power that has a power point cost equal to or lower than his manifester level.

Which confirms that you **cannot** use powers that are from other disciplines.

In the class table, this is the information for level 1:

- Power points per day: 2
- Powers known: 3
- Maximum power level known: 1st

You are probably reading an outdated book.

Also, just in case you are in doubt: a Psion's high Intelligence will grant her more Power points, but not more powers known.